# Formatting for dimensional analysis

Tags: math-mode

I'd like to typeset a problem solution highlighting dimensional analysis in LaTeX.  What is the best way to format the following in LaTeX?

```
  1.345 g | 0.5 L | 1000 cm^3
 ---------|-------|----------- =  0.6725 g
   cm^3   |       |   1 L
```

I could use a table I guess but that seems wrong.  A set of `\frac` commands would also work but not give exactly the same visual affect.  (It would be really nice to cancel the units in the expression as well).   Aside from digging into pstricks is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Quite apart from the appearance, I'm not sure I follow your dimensional analysis here!

Comment: Related questions: [\cancel draws under thing being canceled](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15916/cancel-draws-under-thing-being-canceled) and [cancel package downward arrow](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14385/cancel-package-downward-arrow)

Answer (score 7):

You could definitely use `\frac` to write the LHS components, and the [`cancel` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/cancel) provides a diagonal strike-through of elements. Here's a minimal example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cancel}% http://ctan.org/pkg/cancel
\begin{document}
\[
  \frac{1.345\,\textrm{g}}{1\,\cancel{\textrm{cm}^3}}\,
    \frac{0.5\,\cancel{\textrm{L}}}{1}\,
    \frac{1000\,\cancel{\textrm{cm}^3}}{1\,\cancel{\textrm{L}}}=0.6725\,\textrm{g}
\]
​\end{document}​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

If the SW-NE diagonal crossing through `L` is visually unappealing, `cancel` also provides `\bcancel`, as well as `xcancel` (a combination of `\cancel` and `\bcancel`). The [`siunitx` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) can also be used to write numerals with units in a standard way.

Comment: Seems like you hit 80 [tag:mathmode] answers. ;-)

Comment: Keeping track, are we? `:)`

Comment: Is `\ell` a legal symbol for "liter"? It's used, but not endorsed by the BIPM. The correct spacing for units is `\,`, not `\;`, but perhaps here it can stand.

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15916/cancel-draws-under-thing-being-canceled and  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20643/diagonal-strikeout-starting-too-low-and-ending-too-high for an alternative to `cancel`.

Comment: @egreg: I'll update my answer to reflect the notation choice. Thanks for the note on spacing; looking back at it, I should actually remove the `\,` from `1000` as well, since it is perhaps more common to *not* have that for 4-digit numerals, leading to the initial choice of `\;`.

Comment: @egreg No, `\ell` is not valid here: the only symbols allowed are `l` and `L`.

Comment: You can use the `siunitx` package for the units to make the formatting less annoying. It also integrates with the `cancel` package.